# Parsing String from input as argument issues

Tags: java, string, file, unix

I wanted to add more commands to my java program I am writing in unix but had issues passing the arguments. I just entered in unix the commands before with the text file as a program argument which worked just fine but wanted to ask for the input instead. Tried to fix it on my own but a little new to java

I had ,

```
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input = args[0];
        ///
        String count = args[1];  
        File newF = new File(input); //
        StartProcess start = new StartProcess(input, Integer.parseInt(count));   //begin 

    }
```

which worked just fine, then tried this , which failed

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    //String inputFile = args[0]; //read the input file
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter file");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter number");
    int count = scanner.nextInt();
    //String interruptCounter = args[1];  //read the interrupt value
    File newFile = new File(input); //create a new file with the input file
    StartProcess being = new StartProcess(input, Integer.parseInt(count));   //begin 

}
```

so I got these errors

CPU.java:24: error: incompatible types
        int count = scanner.nextLine();
                                    ^
  required: int
  found:    String
CPU.java:27: error: no suitable method found for parseInt(int)
        StartProcess being = new StartProcess(input, Integer.parseInt(count));   //begin running the process
                                                            ^
    method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
    method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
2 errors

Comment: The compilation errors doesnt seem to be for the code you pasted. The code according to me should compile fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is already an integer - no need to parse the variable

```
StartProcess being = new StartProcess(input, count);
```

Comment: Thank you but that only fixed one of the errors, I still get this errror     java:24: error: incompatible types
        int count = scanner.nextLine();
                                    ^
  required: int
  found:    String
1 error

Comment: That differs from what you have in your 2nd listing - switch it back to `int count = scanner.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

This method `nextLine` returns a String and not integer.

You might want to use this instead.

```
int count = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have input as a string, change to integer and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-inventing the wheel. Use any standart library instead, e.g. [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/).